# java.util.concurrentTimeOutException in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I want to upload 32GB of Data with almost 800 million keys to Hazelast and using 16 machines with 32GB RAM per machine. Several Hazelcast client is uploading the data to the DHT simultaneously.
Suddenly, I started getting the concurrent timeout exception for some client. Can any one tell me what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure it is not java.util.concurrent.TimeOutException ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.... I saw that it's fixed in 3.4.1.